# Shortcuts in PhpStorm on Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard, phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

I've got a problem in PhpStorm with the shortcut. 
All the commands with `/` don't work (Like `⌘/` to comment a line).

The problem is that the default keyboard in PhpStorm is the EN Keyboard. 
I've got a French keyboard. So when I press on `⌘/` PhpStorm detects `⌘:`.

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: It would be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63779 or one of the related tickets. Go through them -- you will find out the reasons and what you may do (possible workarounds etc)

Comment: for german keyboards, see https://victorvolle.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/intellij-german-keyboard-shortcuts-reference/